# How to get the number of satellites using GNSS Status in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-gps, satellite

```
private  lateinit mGnssStatus: GnssStatus  
private  lateinit mGnssStatusCallback: GnssStatus.Callback
private  lateinit mGnssStatusBuild: GnssStatus.Builder
//Gnss initialization to display the number of the satellite 
val mgnssStatus=// how can I initialize GnssStatus correctly to get satellite number               
val Satellitetxt=findViewById<TextView(R.id.Satellitetxt)
Satellitetxt.text = mgnssStatus.satelliteCount.toString()
```

I am trying to use "satelliteCount"; however I don't know how to initialize GnssStatus. Any help please?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You might want to include some more code that is relevant to solving your problem, for example where `mgnssStatus` is declared etc. Also you should provide what errors you are experiencing and what happens when you attempt to run your code. Maybe take a look here to help get more people to take a look at your question - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create GnssStatus with [GnssStatus.Builder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/GnssStatus.Builder), and then you call your object with [getSatelliteCount()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/GnssStatus#getSatelliteCount())

Comment: Can you please take a look again on my code segment because I can not get the point tell now.
when I try to use GnssStatus.Builder  it requires the data about the satellite that I want to add to the build list.